# Parse user input to show as html code. Python + Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have *Publication* class with field for input *tags*.
I capture it with POST method.
The problem is that I can not parse it correctly to be able to use those *tags* as follows (to give them a better look, not just to show a boring string

```
{% for item in tags_string %}
    <p class="badge">{{ item.tag }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

How do I format this **tags_string** so django understands it.

I tried to make a QuerySet using next method, and building a list of dictionaries

```
result = []
for a in tags.split():
   tag_entry = {
        'tag' : a,
    }
    result.append(tag_entry)
```

As a result I receive a line `[{'tag': 'sky'}, {'tag': 'mountain'}]`

my views.py for *create publication* looks like:

```
def create_publication(request):
    a = Publication(publication_title = request.POST['title'], tags = request.POST['tags'])
```

But my page doesn't show anything using mentioned code block.

Comment: What does your view look like?

Comment: I updated my post with this information

Comment: please do on your template {{ item.length }}

Answer (score 0):

**Django view.py**

```
def page_view(request): 

result = {'tag': []}

f = "red, yellow, green, orange"
for tag in f.split(','):
   result['tag'].append(tag)

# create a dictionary 
context = { 
    "tag" : result, 
} 
# return response 
return render(request, "page.html", context)
```

**Django Template:**

```
{% for i in tag %} 
    <div class="row"> 
        {{ i }} 
    </div> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: my bad, I posted with wrong ```code```. I fixed it in my post. That was not the issue.

Comment: it's ok, try this.

Comment: I tried it and the result that I get after code in Django view.py section is: ```{'tag': {'tag': ['red', ' yellow', ' green', ' orange']}}```

Django template doesn't understand it and shows nothing.

Comment: no no no... It should tag : [ ] not  --  tag:tag :[]